# How can I use bash to sequentially increment a numbered directory with a path when creating a copy of the same directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm working on creating a bash script `test.sh` that creates a directory `run1` in the current path and then copies the same bash script into that directory where I need help editing the copied bash script where it should update and increment the directory path to e.g. `run2`. Then I need this to continue indefinitely (e.g. onto `run3` ... `runn`)

I'm looking to run this outside of a for a loop (if possible). This is what I have tried so far (does not work):

**initial test.sh in ${PWD}**

```
i=0
l=$((++i))

# where this path starts off with run1
export ${RUN_DIR}=run$l
export ${TEST_FILE}=test.sh
export ${TOP_LEVEL_PATH}=/home

mkdir -p ${TOP_LEVEL_PATH}/${RUN_DIR}
cd ${RUN_DIR}
cp ${TOP_LEVEL_PATH}/${TEST_FILE} .
bash ${TEST_FILE}

sleep 3s
```

**${PWD} terminal output**

```
test.sh run1
```

**test.sh inside of run1**

```
i=0
l=$((++i))

# where this path then updates to run2
export ${RUN_DIR}=run$l
export ${TEST_FILE}=test.sh
export ${TOP_LEVEL_PATH}=/home

mkdir -p ${TOP_LEVEL_PATH}/${RUN_DIR}
cd ${RUN_DIR}
cp ${TOP_LEVEL_PATH}/${TEST_FILE} .
bash ${TEST_FILE}

sleep 3s
```

**${PWD} terminal output**

```
test.sh run1 run2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to create the `runX` directories all inside your home directory or inside each other? What does `${PWD} terminal output` mean? `PWD` is a shell variable, not a command. And even if you print its value with, e.g., `echo ${PWD}`, it will show the current directory, not its content.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) or a really complicated attempt to fill up a file system.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I want to create the `runX` inside of the home directory and not inside of each other. `${PWD} terminal output` is the home directory path.

Comment: "_I want to create the runX inside of the home directory_": then why not `mkdir run{1..N}` where `N` is the largest number you wish? And sorry, I don't understand what "_`${PWD} terminal output` is the home directory path_" means.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework exercise. If it is not consider changing your specifications, they are really artificial. It is not 100% clear but I will assume that you want to create each `runX` directory inside the previous one, not all in your home directory.

What you tried has 2 issues: 1) you don't increment your counter. 2) you create all your subdirectories inside your home directory.

But more important, you apparently did not understand the difference between variable names (`RUN_DIR`) and variables expansion (`${RUN_DIR}`). To assign variable `RUN_DIR` use:

```
RUN_DIR=<value>
```

not:

```
${RUN_DIR}=<value>
```

Back to your 2 issues. You can fix the first issue by using only variable `i` (and thus getting rid of `l`), transforming the file with `awk` while copying it in the newly created directory:

```
awk -F'=' '/^i=[0-9]+$/ {$2+=1} {print}' OFS='=' test.sh > $RUN_DIR/test.sh
```

This command considers the `test.sh` file as a list of records (lines) of `=` separated fields (`-F'='` and `OFS='='`). If a record is exactly `i=<a number>` (`/^i=[0-9]+$/`), awk increments the number (`{$2+=1}`). All lines are then printed (`{print}`). The output is sent to the newly created script (`$RUN_DIR/test.sh`).

The second issue is even easier to fix swap some commands and use relative paths instead of absolute paths:

```
i=1

# where this path then updates to run2
RUN_DIR="run$i"
TEST_FILE=test.sh

mkdir -p "$RUN_DIR"
cd "$RUN_DIR" || exit
awk -F'=' '/^i=[0-9]+$/ {$2+=1} {print}' OFS='=' "../$TEST_FILE" > "$TEST_FILE"
bash "$TEST_FILE"

sleep 3s
```

Demo:

```
$ ./test.sh
^C
$ ls -R run1
run1:

run2  test.sh

run1/run2:
run3  test.sh

run1/run2/run3:
run4  test.sh

run1/run2/run3/run4:
test.sh

$ cat run1/run2/run3/run4/test.sh
i=5
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> [...] then copies the same bash script into that directory where I need help editing the copied bash script where it should update and increment the directory path to e.g. `run2`

You can edit your bash script using a tool like `awk`.

By the way, the `sleep` in your script has no effect because you execute the copied script first, which will never terminate. Also, you might want to run the next script using `exec` to save some resources; otherwise your first process will have infinite (grand-)child processes.

```
#! /bin/bash
i=1
nextdir="run$i"
self=$(basename "$BASH_SOURCE") &&
mkdir -p "$nextdir" &&
awk -F= '/^i=/{$2++} 1' "$self" > "$nextdir/$self" &&
sleep 3 &&
cd "$nextdir" &&
exec bash "$self"
```

The `&&` make sure that the script exits if something goes wrong, for instance if the next `runX` directory could not be created.

As an alternative for actually editing the bash script, you could set an environment variable with the incremented number or parse the working directory name.